# Python merge 2 dataframes, transpose the 2nd table as shown

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, transpose

Could anyone please help, how to merge the below 2 tables,
on 'ID' so that the 2nd table is transposed as shown bellow

Base Table 1.

[image]

2. table to transpose

[image]

Result I need

[image]

Comment: You want duplicate column names in your output?

Comment: Please don't use image (expect for output). Update your post with plain text data.

Comment: @Chris yes as in the 3rd table

Comment: @Corralien alright will edit the first 2 tables